# Running apache as an unpreviledged user

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I've heard that one could run the apache2 web-service as just a user without having root access privileges. How could I do this?

I'm not asking if I could set up Apache to run as a user (say for security reasons), but rather as a user how can I run Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure Apache to bind to a high port (above 1024), such as 8080.  Unless the admins have gone to unusual lengths to prohibit the practise, non-root users can bind to high ports with any program they wish to.  The problem is that with a non-standard port, you need to explicitly point your browser to the port:

```
http://www.example.com:8080
```

Comment: Having done this, it's also possible for the admins to add an iptables rule to make your server also appear on a low port such as 80.